# How to fix "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0"

Tags: mysql

I created a simple program in Visual Studio. I made an installer and I tried to install it on my computer (the one I used to create the program) and when I run it, it works fine. Now the problem is, when I installed it on a different pc (it doesn't have visual studio) and run the program, it shows this error.

[image: Error]

I browsed on existing questions here in SO and all I found are same errors DURING PROGRAM CREATION. More like they are not yet finished with the program. My problem is how to fix this error WHEN RUNNING IT ON A DIFFERENT PC AFTER INSTALLATION. Could someone please help me? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't export MySql.Data.dll in your project.

Have you check if that file is in the install folder in the computer in which it is not working?
In this case you have to set the Copy Local properties to True. See details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx)